# Having difficulty rotating a sprite along a path in Java.

Tags: java, animation, game-physics, slick2d

I am currently creating a simple game in Slick2D that requires a plan to fly along a set path determined by the user. Currently, I have the plane (which is a sprite) that can follow a path of coordinates. However, I am having difficulty rotating the plane sprite so that the nose of the plane is following the path.

I wrote the following method to help calculate the angle of rotation that the plane needs, but it doesn't seem to be working properly. Any help is appreciated!

```
/**
 * Calculate the rotation for the plane 
 * @return The rotation in degrees that the plane must do 
 */
public int calculateRotation()
{
    int[] spriteCenter = {locationX + width/2, locationY + height/2};   
    double deltaX = spriteCenter[0] - target[0];
    double deltaY = spriteCenter[1] - target[1];

    double theta = Math.atan2(deltaY,deltaX);

    return (int) Math.toDegrees(theta);
}
```

Comment: did you checkout: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292774/calculating-rotation-along-a-path?rq=1 ?

Comment: Yes I did, but I'm having some trouble understanding it as it seems to be rather advanced (My trig is pretty Rusty). My understanding is that this shouldn't be that hard to implement.