# Compute target roll, pitch and yaw angles given initial and target positions and intial roll, pitch and yaw angles

Tags: opengl, vector, graphics, 3d, robotics

I have a model that moves in simulation world. The frame of operation is right handed with X - forward, Y - left and Z - Up.

I know the current position, `P1 (x1, y1, z1)` and current RPY angles, `(R1, P1, Y1)`. I have a goal position, `P2 (x2, y2, z2)`. I would like to move my model from `P1` to `P2`. I am stuck at computing the goal RPY angles. I would like my model to turn around first in the direction from P1 to P2 and move in that direction to reach goal.

How do I calculate the target RPY angles, `(R2, P2, Y2)`, given the above information ?

Comment: Two points give a direction. You cannot compute roll from a direction, only its yaw and pitch.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Thanks, I can retain the current roll. Could you please tell me how to calculate pitch and yaw ?

Comment: Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292774/calculating-rotation-along-a-path)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Calculate the direction vector `D = P2 - P1 = (x2 - x1, y2 - y1, z2 - z1)`
- Pitch `P2 = asin(Dz / |D|)`
- Yaw `Y2 = atan2(Dy, Dx)`

(NB can use `P2 = atan2(Dz, sqrt(Dx^2 + Dy^2))`  instead for more robustness near the spherical poles)